# dart CLI command -why no lib/proj.dart file? dart ctreate <project_name>

Tags: dart, command-line-interface

whenever I used dart CLI command

```
dart create <project_name>
```

i used to get a nice project folder with a lib/project.dart file inside the file there would be a some nice peace of code like this:

```
int calculate() {
  return 6 * 8;
}
```

which you would import in the main file. a nice touch overall. but there is no lib folder or file, why??

i am using linux OS, dart version 2.3:

Dart SDK version: 2.13.4 (stable) (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64"

Answer (score 2):

If you run:

```
dart create --help
```

You get the following with Dart version 2.14.1 (properly also 2.13.x but I don't have that version):

```
Create a new Dart project.

Usage: dart create [arguments] <directory>
-h, --help        Print this usage information.
-t, --template    The project template to use.
                  [console-simple (default), console-full, package-simple, server-shelf, web-simple]
    --[no-]pub    Whether to run 'pub get' after the project has been created.
                  (defaults to on)
    --force       Force project generation, even if the target directory already exists.

Run "dart help" to see global options.

Available templates:
  console-simple: A simple command-line application. (default)
    console-full: A command-line application sample.
  package-simple: A starting point for Dart libraries or applications.
    server-shelf: A server app using `package:shelf`
      web-simple: A web app that uses only core Dart libraries.
```

So the default type of project is `console-simple` (I suppose that by "simple" it means we don't split the logic of our application into `bin`, `lib` and `test`) but we can change that by doing e.g.

```
dart create --template console-full hello_world
```

Which does contain the `bin`, `lib` and `test` folders:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        12-09-2021     22:20                .dart_tool
d-----        12-09-2021     22:20                bin
d-----        12-09-2021     22:20                lib
d-----        12-09-2021     22:20                test
-a----        12-09-2021     22:20            113 .gitignore
-a----        12-09-2021     22:20           5328 .packages
-a----        12-09-2021     22:20           1038 analysis_options.yaml
-a----        12-09-2021     22:20             29 CHANGELOG.md
-a----        12-09-2021     22:20           7907 pubspec.lock
-a----        12-09-2021     22:20            242 pubspec.yaml
-a----        12-09-2021     22:20            122 README.md
```